# How do I install Cypress using CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY?

Tags: shell, cmd, binary, cypress

Due to company firewall I cannot just use npm install cypress.

I have the cypress.zip in my downloads folder

On windows command prompt I have tried the below:
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/Users/HMiller/Downloads/cypress.zip npm install cypress
And i get the below error

'CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Or in Shell I get this-

CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/Users/HMiller/Downloads/cypress.zip : The term
'CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/Users/HMiller/Downloads/cypress.zip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/Users/HMiller/Downloads/cypress.zip npm insta ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CYPRESS_INSTALL...ads/cypress.zip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you refer this - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#Install-binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Try These steps,

`set CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=\your\path\to\cypress.x.x.x.zip`

`npm install cypress`

`npx cypress open`

If you are trying to add  scripts in package.json

```
  "test": "npm run cypressinstallbinary && npx cypress run",
  "cypressinstallbinary": 
  "CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/path/to/cypress.zip npm install cypress",
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I ran the first command with no issues, but when running the second i receive the below error
npm ERR! Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration
npm ERR! Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:
npm ERR! URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/9.6.1?platform=win32&arch=x64
npm ERR! Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
npm ERR! Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.19044)

Comment: I've also tried npm config set http_proxy=.... and npm config set strict-ssl false